# Unable to click on dropdown within iframe - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

The problem: trying to click on a drop-down within an iframe using Chrome driver and Selenium with Python.

Hi all. A user kindly helped me with a newbie query yesterday. I was unable to click on a link within a url and this was because I had to switch into an iframe. This part of the code now works and I navigate to a drop-down menu for which I wish to make a selection.

I've tried accessing this element through amending my code but receive the traceback that it is unable to locate the element. I am trying to change the value of the drop-down to 'Aldershot' using Select, finding the element by name and visible text. Any advice greatly appreciated.

```
#setup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

#utilise chrome driver to open specified webpage
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/philthomas/Desktop/web/chromedriver")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http:enfa.co.uk")

#switch to specific iframe and click on 'clubs' button on left hand menu
driver.switch_to.frame(2);
ClubsLink=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
"//span[contains(text(),'Clubs')]")))
ClubsLink.click()

#find drop-down menu and choose 'Aldershot'
select_box = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("team"))
select_box.select_by_visible_text("Aldershot")
```

**Traceback:**

[image: Traceback]

**HTML:**

[image: HTML from url]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting error because the select dropdown present inside an iframe.
You need to switch to iframe first inorder to select the element.

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

#utilise chrome driver to open specified webpage
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/philthomas/Desktop/web/chromedriver")

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http:enfa.co.uk")

#switch to specific iframe and click on 'clubs' button on left hand menu
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"left")))
ClubsLink=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
"//span[contains(text(),'Clubs')]")))
ClubsLink.click()

#return from iframe
driver.switch_to.default_content()
#Switch to another iframe
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"main")))

#find drop-down menu and choose 'Aldershot'
teamselect=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"team")))
select_box = Select(teamselect)
select_box.select_by_visible_text("Aldershot")
```

**Browser snapshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for this reply, works fantastically. Is there a specific course/tutorial you followed to learn this particular approach or just a case of working through the specific Selenium docs? Am keen to improve and learn more as still very new to programming. Many thanks

Comment: No such specific document.Just follow selenium official document you will get most of the things.